# ¿Cómo evitar que scroll haga llamado de IndexOf de IList?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una implementación de `IList` para virtualizar el contenido de una colección,  esto con la finalidad de evitar tener todos los registros en memoria, así que guardo todos los registros en un archivo de SQLite y solo conservo algunos en memoria.

```
public class DataCollection : IList, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    int IList.IndexOf(object item)
    {
        if (item == null) return -1;
        return IndexOf(item as ElementData);
    }

    private int IndexOf(ElementData element)
    {
        try
        {
            if (element == null)
                return -1;

            if(!isFiltered)
                return element.Id - 1;

            //en esta funcion es donde se ejecuta el query
            return _elementsCache.FetchIndex(element.Id);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Aparente todo funciona muy bien, pero al alcanzar mas de 200k registros en una de las colecciones (tengo 3 hasta el momento), empiezan a notarse problemas de rendimiento en el Thread de GUI. Descubrí que la GUI está constantemente pidiendo el `IndexOf` de al menos 75 elementos (segun mis calculos) y esto sucede cada vez que el scroll cambia.
Tengo una funcionalidad llamada `Auto Scroll` que lo que hace es mantener la barra de scroll al máximo. Esto mantiene un constante cambio en el valor de scroll y este a su vez está llamando la función `IndexOf` de la colección.

El problema más notorio es cuando la colección tiene un filtro, ya que el `ID` del elemento es diferente al indice, es decir, cuando no tengo filtro me basta con hacer un `ID - 1` para obtener su índice, pero si la colección está filtrada, tengo que revisar en qué índice se encuentra dicho `ID`, para esto hago una consulta a `SQLite` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT [index] FROM ElementData WHERE ElementId=<elementid>
```

> Esta consulta me consume un promedio de 1 ms, ya que `ElementId` es un index.

Este seria mi XAML del `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name                                          ="FilteredElementsListView" 
          GridViewColumnHeader.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown ="GridViewColumnHeaderPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
          PreviewLostKeyboardFocus                        ="FilteredElementsListViewPreviewLostKeyboardFocus"                    
          TextOptions.TextFormattingMode                  ="Display" 
          TextOptions.TextHintingMode                     ="Animated"
          PreviewKeyDown                                  ="FilteredElementsListViewPreviewKeyDown" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan                                 ="3"
          Margin                                          ="0,0,0,-0.333"                      
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode            ="Recycling">
```

`Style` para todos los `ListView`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
     <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
     <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True" />
     <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
     <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
     <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
     .
     .
     .
</Style>
```

¿Alguna idea como pudiera evitar este llamado constante de `IndexOf` en el cambio de scroll?

Comment: Es posible que por alguna razón la virtualización del ListView esté deshabilitada. Lee [este documento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls) a ver si puede darte una pista.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo habia leido y tengo aplicadas todas las recomendaciones que ahi mencionan. Por cierto, he agregado el `Style` del `ListView` con esas propiedades.